# Why different kind of UI when running on salesforce vf page and locally in desktop

Tags: html, bootstrap

I am running the below code both locally and in salesforce. But why i am getting different kind of UI look.

Locally -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Multiselect</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/mohapats/Desktop/trst/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/mohapats/Desktop/trst/bootstrap-example.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/mohapats/Desktop/trst/prettify.css" type="text/css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/mohapats/Desktop/trst/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/mohapats/Desktop/trst/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/mohapats/Desktop/trst/prettify.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/mohapats/Desktop/trst/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/mohapats/Desktop/trst/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#affix">


        <div class="container">
                          <div class="example">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
                                    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
                                    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
                                    <option value="Mozzarella">Mozzarella</option>
                                    <option value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
                                    <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
                                    <option value="Onions">Onions</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

UI -

[image]

Salesforce -

```
<apex:page>
<head>
<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, 'jquery-2.1.3.min.js')}"> </apex:includescript>
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, 'bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css')}"/>
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, 'bootstrap-example.css')}"/>
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, 'bootstrap-multiselect.css')}"/>
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, 'prettify.css')}"/>

<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, 'bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js')}"> </apex:includescript>
<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, 'bootstrap-multiselect.js')}"> </apex:includescript>

<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, 'prettify.js')}"> </apex:includescript>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#affix">


        <div class="container">
                          <div class="example">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
                                    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
                                    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
                                    <option value="Mozzarella">Mozzarella</option>
                                    <option value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
                                    <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
                                    <option value="Onions">Onions</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

UI -

[image]

What i need to do to get similar kind of UI look.

Regards

Comment: If you just google `Visualforce Bootstrap` you will find [Twitter Bootstrap and Visualforce in Minutes](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/03/twitter-bootstrap-and-visualforce-in-minutes.html), which critically links to [VisualStrap](http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/ProjectDetail?id=a0290000009MI61).

Comment: I'm wondering if the Salesforce standard stylesheets might be conflicting with your own.  You could try disabling them `<apex:page standardStyleSheets="false"...>`

Comment: i tried but it is same as before..No change..